# git upstream is gone after removing remote branch

Tags: git

I appear to have got my git in a mess.

I first of all renamed a branch that was named a branch `Sprint/13/Story/XXX-11`

using this:

`git branch -m Sprint13/Story/XXX-11`

This did not rename it remotely and my git status was full of messages about unmerged and unpulled changes.

So I thought I would then just delete the remote branch so I did this:

`git branch --delete --remotes origin/Sprint/13/Story/XXX-11`

Now when I do git status, I get the following message:

`Your branch is based on 'origin/Sprint/13/Story/XXX-11', but the upstream is gone.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you have actually done so far

```
git branch -m Sprint13/Story/XXX-11
```

This renamed the *local* branch `Sprint/13/Story/XXX-11` to `Sprint13/Story/XXX-11`

Then you did this

```
git branch --delete --remotes origin/Sprint/13/Story/XXX-11
```

This deleted the remote *tracking* branch of your original branch.  Note that this branch is actual local, and serves as the sync-up point for your local branch every time you pull from the remote repository.

To fix the situation, I think you should first delete the renamed branch locally:

```
git branch -d Sprint13/Story/XXX-11      # delete local new renamed branch
```

Then push your old local branch to the remote under the new name:

```
git push origin Sprint/13/Story/XXX-11:Sprint13/Story/XXX-11
```

Now you can pull this branch down to your local Git via:

```
git pull origin Sprint13/Story/XXX-11
```

In the process, Git will also create a local tracking branch for you which points to the right location.

For cleanup, you can now delete the old local branch as well as its remote counterpart:

```
git branch -d Sprint/13/Story/XXX-11      # delete old local branch
git push origin :Sprint/13/Story/XXX-11   # delete old remote branch
```

Comment: Even if I do this, the remote branch is still called Sprint/13/Story/PEN-6021.

Comment: You are helping me, take your time.

Comment: Use `git push origin local-name:remote-name` to get the name you want on the remote.

Comment: No matter what I try the remote branch is the still named the same.  Could it be something in my .git/refs folder?

Comment: @dagda1 I updated my answer, please have a look.  I recommend just pushing your old local branch to the remote under a new name.

Comment: deleting the local branch cured all ills.  Many thanks

Comment: The problem was that even though we fixed everything else, the old local branch still "thought" it was the same in some way.  Also checkout the answer by @VonC which might be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

First, the syntax to rename a branch is:

```
git branch -m [<oldbranch>] <newbranch>
```

So you need to be sure you had  `Sprint/13/Story/XXX-11` checked out before the rename.
To be sure, type the full rename command:

```
git branch -m Sprint/13/Story/XXX-11 Sprint13/Story/XXX-11
```

Then you can check with `git branch` if your current branch is renamed.

Finally, this does not influence the remote tracking branch.

You need to do a:

```
git push -u origin Sprint13/Story/XXX-11
```

to create a remote branch of the same name on the remote repo.
And `git push origin :Sprint/13/Story/XXX-11`  to delete the old one.